# Commit rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm working to optimize my website in ror. The rails version is 2.3.5.
So, I log mysql query. And I see what rails use transaction (begin commit) to create or update object in database.
This method use my server resource and I would like to know how I can disable this commit ?

I don't find a configuration for this thing.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Ruby on Rails uses "my server resource" too - and a lot of it! Why not simply ditch all of that and switch to writing in C?

Answer (score 2):

This is a terrible idea.

However, you could switch to the MyISAM table type, which does not support transactions.

Comment: Yes I know that is not a good idea but my server is very slow.

Comment: I'm guessing you've got bigger problems than this, and Rails itself is no speed demon.